# printf working unexpectedly

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to write a code for a problem in C. The code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int cop(int a,int b)
{
    int c,d,e,f,g;
    if(a>b)
    {   
        c=a;
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }
    while(c!=0)
    {
        c=b%a;
        b=a;
        a=c;
    }
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    int i=1, j=1, k, a, b, c, d, e, f, g=1;

    scanf("%d",&k);
    int q=0;
    for(q=k;q>0;q--)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a);
        while(g==1)
        {
            b=j+i;
            i=j;
            j=b;
            g=cop(j,a);
            printf("%d\n",g);
        }
        printf("%d %d\n",g,j);
        j=1;i=1;g=1;
    }

return 0;
}
```

When I give input as `3 3 5 161` it was printing

```
1
3
3 3
1
1
5
5 5
1
1
1
1
1
7
7 21
```

and when i comment out the statement `printf("%d\n",g)` and execute with the same input i get the output as follows:

```
3 3
5 3
161 3
```

So, my doubt is why I am not getting:-

```
3 3
5 5
7 21
```

Comment: So what do you want to do exactly? I cannot understand by just reading your code. And I got a different result when inputing `3 3 5 161`.

Comment: It sounds like you should run your code with a debugger attached.

Comment: oh you think `printf` distorted your output some how? or you wrote your logic incorrectly? which is it?

Comment: You cannot "doubt" something that you don't understand. Perhaps you can "be puzzled by" it, but you're certainly not in a position to *doubt* it.

Comment: Always compile with warnings enabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foo.c: In function 'cop':
foo.c:4: warning: 'c' may be used uninitialized in this function
```

Does this help?

You're depending on an uninitialized value in your function (in some cases). This means that the extra call to printf could dirty a register or a stack value and that will change how your function behaves.

Strictly speaking it's an undefined behavior and you just got a lesson on how undefined behavior can look like - unrelated function calls change how the undefined behavior behaves.